# Get the selected value of the second list box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning JavaScript. What I am trying to achieve, basically, is when I select the Brand, it will display only the Model list box of that specific brand. Can you help me on how to get the value of the selected second list?

```
<select id="txtBrand">
    <option value="HP" id="HP">HP</option>
    <option value="Dell">Dell</option>
    <option value="Toshiba">Toshiba</option>
</select>
<br>    <strong>Model:</strong>

<select id="txtHPModel">
    <option value="HP">HP Pavilion</option>
    <option value="Dell">HP Elitebooks</option>
    <option value="Toshiba">HP Probooks</option>
</select>
<select id="txtDellModel" hidden="hidden">
    <option value="HP">Dell Vostro</option>
    <option value="Dell">Dell Inspiron</option>
    <option value="Toshiba">Dell Latitude</option>
</select>
<select id="txtToshibaModel" hidden="hidden">
    <option value="HP">Toshiba Portege</option>
    <option value="Dell">Toshiba Tecra</option>
    <option value="Toshiba">Dell Satellite</option>
</select>

$(compbrand).click(function () {
    if (compbrand.value == "HP") {
        $(hp).removeAttr('disabled').show() $(dell).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
        $(toshiba).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
    }
    if (compbrand.value == "Dell") {
        $(dell).removeAttr('disabled').show() $(hp).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
        $(toshiba).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
    }
    if (compbrand.value == "Toshiba") {
        $(toshiba).removeAttr('disabled').show() $(hp).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
        $(dell).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: What's `compbrand` supposed to be? And there is no `hidden` attribute; instead use CSS to show/hide: `display: none`.

Comment: I think compbrand is $('#txtBrand')

Comment: @DavidThomas as ids are copied as window property.. that should be work

Comment: @Arun: if by that you mean that using the `id` as a variable-name should work: yes, I know - although I'd argue that it's a terrible idea, and one that should not be encouraged. But there is no element with an `id` equal to 'compbrand'. Also, while I suspect that melvas is correct, I'd much prefer to have the OP take the time to clarify. Assumptions make for bad code. And, regarding your own code, and further to my own original comment, there is no (valid) `hidden` property/attribute.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.Yes, combrand is $('#txtBrand')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a change event handler, in which based on the selected value you can set the model visibility.

Also assign a common class to all model select elements to make it easy to select.

```js
$('#txtBrand').change(function() {
  var $current = $('#txt' + this.value + 'Model').show();
  $('.txt-model').not($current).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="txtBrand">
  <option value="HP" id="HP">HP</option>
  <option value="Dell">Dell</option>
  <option value="Toshiba">Toshiba</option>
</select>

Model:

<select id="txtHPModel" class="txt-model">
  <option value="HP">HP Pavilion</option>
  <option value="Dell">HP Elitebooks</option>
  <option value="Toshiba">HP Probooks</option>
</select>
<select id="txtDellModel" hidden="hidden" class="txt-model">
  <option value="HP">Dell Vostro</option>
  <option value="Dell">Dell Inspiron</option>
  <option value="Toshiba">Dell Latitude</option>
</select>
<select id="txtToshibaModel" hidden="hidden" class="txt-model">
  <option value="HP">Toshiba Portege</option>
  <option value="Dell">Toshiba Tecra</option>
  <option value="Toshiba">Dell Satellite</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun for the neat code. How will I get the value of the selected model and pass it to variable?

Comment: @JessieBear how do you want the data?

Comment: I need the value of Brand and Model. I am adding data in SharePoint list item.

Answer (score 0):

```
// IYour HTML Change "hidden="hidden" TO style="displayn:none"
```

$("#txtBrand").change(function () {

```
    var brand= this.value;
    if (brand== "HP") {
        $('#txtHPModel').fadeIn();
         $('#txtDellModel').fadeOut();
         $('#txtToshibaModel').fadeOut();

    } else if(brand== "Dell") {
       $('#txtHPModel').fadeOut();
         $('#txtDellModel').fadeIn();
         $('#txtToshibaModel').fadeOut();


    }else{
  $('#txtHPModel').fadeOut();
         $('#txtDellModel').fadeOut();
         $('#txtToshibaModel').fadeIn();

}
```

});